# White space between few iframes

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a few iframes on page and need the first one scalling.
But when I make this: http://tak.robi.to/scale/index2.htm
after scalling, there's white space/gap between first and second one.
I need to set a space between first and second one always to 20px (even it scalling).

```css
 #slider {
          width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
       <iframe id="iframe" style="margin-top: 10px;" src="1.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="200px">
       </iframe>
       <iframe id="iframe" style="margin-top: 10px;" src="2.html" frameborder="0" width="100%">
       </iframe>
```

Please help. I'm a graphic designer and really having problem with this :(

Answer (score 0):

[image]First, ids are unique, see IDs and Classes: https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/
Use classes instead or `id="iframe1"` and `id="iframe2`, e.g. `iframe1` with `margin-bottom: 10px` and `iframe2` with `margin-top: 10px` or only `iframe1` with `margin-bottom: 20px`...

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I  made this:
`<iframe id="iframe1" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" src="1.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="200px"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe2" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" src="2.html" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe>`

here is live: http://tak.robi.to/scale/index2.htm
after scaling there is still large white space :(

Comment: Sorry, but which type of scaling do you mean? Do you mean scaling your browser window or scaling the frames?

Comment: Which browser do you use? Can you show me your freshest code? I added an image to my answer for clarification.

Comment: I use chrome and FF. Here is my actual work: http://tak.robi.to/scale/index2.htm
I think the problem is int the files that I want show in iframe

Comment: The included iframe file can't influence the parent file (with some exeptions).